# Gnu Parallel is ignoring the (--sshlogin) attribute order when used with (--keep-order ) option

Tags: gnu-parallel

Here is my example where I request that the job runs on LNXVP1262 first before starting on LNXVP1251.

```
date ; echo 'hostname;date;sleep 10;date' | parallel --no-run-if-empty --will-cite --onall --keep-order --joblog ${runDir}/jobLog.txt --results ${runDir}/resultsDir --jobs 1 --sshlogin LNXVP1262,LNXVP1251
```

Results:

```
Wed Sep  6 17:35:01 EDT 2023

LNXVP1251

Wed Sep  6 17:35:02 EDT 2023

Wed Sep  6 17:35:12 EDT 2023

LNXVP1262

Wed Sep  6 17:35:13 EDT 2023

Wed Sep  6 17:35:23 EDT 2023
```

How can I make sure the results are:

Wed Sep  6 17:35:01 EDT 2023

```
LNXVP1262

Wed Sep  6 17:35:02 EDT 2023

Wed Sep  6 17:35:12 EDT 2023

LNXVP1251

Wed Sep  6 17:35:13 EDT 2023

Wed Sep  6 17:35:23 EDT 2023
```

Is the (--sshlogin) login order always alphabetical (I am assuming) or is there a way to force a sort order.  I suppose one hack is creating SSH machine aliases in a sort order, and hope parallel can use the aliases, but that’s ugly.

Comment: I already use "--keep-order" in my example and the question subject

Answer (score 0):

From `man parallel`:

```
   --keep-order
   -k  Keep sequence of output same as the order of input.
       :
       If used with --onall or --nonall the output will grouped by
       sshlogin in sorted order.
```

So `sshlogin`s will be sorted when using `-k`.

If you do not use `-k` the order of the output is based on which job completes first.

The order in which you give `sshlogin`s on the command line has no effect:

```
$ parallel --sshdelay 1 --tag -S127.0.0.{22,1,33,222,11,3,2,111} --onall echo ::: foo
127.0.0.1       foo
127.0.0.11      foo
127.0.0.111     foo
127.0.0.2       foo
127.0.0.22      foo
127.0.0.222     foo
127.0.0.3       foo
127.0.0.33      foo
$ parallel --sshdelay 1 --tag -S127.0.0.{22,33,11,222,111,1,3,2} --onall echo ::: foo
127.0.0.1       foo
127.0.0.11      foo
127.0.0.111     foo
127.0.0.2       foo
127.0.0.22      foo
127.0.0.222     foo
127.0.0.3       foo
127.0.0.33      foo
```